# phpunit testing a json object for one of two values

Tags: phpunit

How do I use php unittest to check that a json object has one of 2 values

`{"option":valule}`... value can be either 0 or 1

I want some like

```
$optionValue = {"option":0};

$data = json-decode($optionValue);    
this->containOnly(0,1, $data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->assertThat ($data["option"], 
                   $this->logicalOr ($this->equalTo (1), $this->equalTo (0)));
```